# How to pack the py file into an exe file and run it on a machine that doesn't have python installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, exe

I have a python file using opencv and numpy libraries, now I want to pack it into an exe file to launch, and it can be run on a machine that does not have python and the above libraries installed. Is there a way to fulfill that request?
Hope everybody help please. Thanks a lot

I searched online for libraries like PyInstaller, ... but it didn't meet all my requirements

Update: I read all the other questions before asking this question

Comment: Try auto py to exe.

Comment: What was the issue with PyInstaller? [Here](http://www.py2exe.org/) is another option.

Comment: I tried both of those libraries, but it doesn't recognize opencv